# Problem with Kibana unable to load Dashboards (Exiting: resource 'metricbeat-7.5.0' exists, but it is not an alias)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, metricbeat, elastic-beats

I have installed metric-beat , but unable to load he kibana dashboard for mongodb.

i am getting below error,
[10.0.1.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [service.address] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:759) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]

in client its showing "Exiting: resource 'metricbeat-7.5.0' exists, but it is not an alias"

Comment: How did you install metricbeat? Did you follow all the steps in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-getting-started.html), specifically steps 3 and 4?

Comment: Did you take a look at this:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/exiting-resource-metricbeat-7-4-2-exists-but-it-is-not-an-alias/206685/2

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:9200/metricbeat-7.5.0
```

Then try to load the dashboards again.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to an alias issue of the current index in Elasticsearch
I was able to **RESOLVE** this.

Root Cause :
In my case the live index name was **filebeat-7.17.1** which is required as the alias. From the system of Elasticsearch, it's notpermit to set the alias, which is used a index name already.

**RESOLVED**  :

- Backed up existing index

  ```
    POST _reindex {
       "source": {
           "index": "filebeat-7.17.1"
       },
       "dest": {
           "index": "filebeat-7.17.1_new"
       }
    }
  ```
- Delete the erroneous index
- Update **index template** with correct alias (mark data-stream to auto create)
- Update **index lifecycle policy** for index rollover [[ref]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-apply-policy)